# Corona Physics Body - Detecting Position

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk, game-physics, detection

I'm having some trouble with tracking a physics body for a game that I am writing using Corona SDK (full code can be found here: https://github.com/prafull2001/JumperCorona)

I am applying a linear impulse to all of my obstacle objects to get them moving but I want to get them to stop after they reach a certain X position. I thought I wrote the code correctly, but the compiler is telling me otherwise....

**PLEASE NOTE** I am experiencing my trouble in the **badguy.move()** function.

My Files:

Main:

```
local Physics = require("physics")
Physics.start()


centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY



myScene = require("scene")
myHero = require("hero")
myGoomba = require("badguy")
myButtons = require("buttons")
myMenu = require("mainmenu")


myMenu.drawMainMenu()
playButton:addEventListener( "tap", myMenu.play )





--[[
function onCollision( event )
    if (event.phase == "began") then
        print("began: " .. "The " .. event.object1.name .. " hit the " .. event.object2.name .. ".")
        local youLose = display.newText("You Lose!", display.contentCenterX, 20, native.systemFont, 40)
        youLose:setFillColor(0, 0, 0)
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
]]
```

Main Menu:

```
local mainmenu = {}

local Physics = require("physics")
Physics.start()


function mainmenu.drawMainMenu()

    menuTheme = audio.loadStream("Music/menuTheme.ogg")
    menuThemeChannel = audio.play( menuTheme, { channel=1, loops=-1, fadein=3000 } )

    background = display.newImage("menuBackground.png")
    background.x = display.contentCenterX
    background.y = display.contentCenterY
    background:scale(1.2, 1.2)

    playButton = display.newImage("playButton.png")
    playButton.x = display.contentCenterX
    playButton.y = display.contentCenterY - 75
    playButton:scale( .3, .3 )

end


function mainmenu.play()


    print("mainmenu - tap registered, preparing to load game..")

    playButton:removeEventListener( "tap", myMenu.play )

    audio.stop(1)

    myScene.sayHello()
    myScene.drawScene()


    myHero.sayHello()
    myHero.drawHero() 


    myGoomba.hello()
    myGoomba.drawBadGuy()


    myButtons.sayHello()
    myButtons.drawButtons()


    myGoomba.move()


    gameTheme = audio.loadStream("Music/playTheme.ogg")
    gameThemeChannel = audio.play( gameTheme, { channel=2, loops=-1, fadein=0 } )


    jumpButton:addEventListener("tap", myButtons.jump)
    backButton:addEventListener("tap", myButtons.goBack)



end



function mainmenu.sayHello()
    print("mainmenu - Hello....")
end


return mainmenu
```

Bad Guy:

```
local badguy = {}

local Physics = require("physics")
Physics.start()






function badguy.hello()
    print("badguy - hello...")
end


function badguy.drawBadGuy()

    obstacle = {}

    obstacle[1] = display.newImage( "asteroid.png")
    obstacle[1].x = 300
    obstacle[1].y = 275 
    obstacle[1]:scale(.7, .7)
    Physics.addBody(obstacle[1], "dynamic", {radius = 20, bounce = 0})

    obstacle[2] = display.newImage( "asteroid.png")
    obstacle[2].x = 400
    obstacle[2].y = 275
    obstacle[2]:scale(.7, .7)
    Physics.addBody(obstacle[2], "dynamic", {radius = 20, bounce = 0})

    obstacle[3] = display.newImage( "asteroid.png")
    obstacle[3].x = 500
    obstacle[3].y = 275
    obstacle[3]:scale(.7, .7)
    Physics.addBody(obstacle[3], "dynamic", {radius = 20, bounce = 0})


end



function badguy.move()

--get badguy to spawn back at start after they cross a certain x value and
--game should restart upon contact  

    for i = 1, #obstacle, 1 do
        obstacle[i]:setLinearVelocity( -200, 0 )

            if (obstacle[i].x < 100) then
                print("if statement activated")

                obstacle[i]:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
            end

    end
end




function badguy.sayHello()
    print("badguy - Hello....")
end


return badguy
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want the asteroid sprites to respawn at the right of the screen once they pass a certain x value near the player. (basically creating a respawn function for the asteroids). I thought I did so in the badguy.move() function using the nested if statement but it's not working...

Comment: It doesn't work because you detect asteroid passed a certain x value near the player only once.  Try add `Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", myGoomba.move)` instead of `myGoomba.move()`. Remeber also to remove `enterFrame` event. Read more about it on Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html).

Comment: Do you think I could contact you via email or any other forms of messaging? I have some other problems I really need taken care of and I'm pretty much a beginner at Corona :(

Comment: I'm also beginner. By answering different question here I try improve my skills and help others:) I recommended you put your questions on Corona [forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com) and/or read a lot [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com).

Comment: OK thanks, I'll post in the Corona forum :)